# How does a CheckBoxTableCell propagate changes back?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a particular question about the JavaFX library that might reveal a flaw in my understanding of the JavaFX-Framework in general.

Let us assume that there is an Entity class called `Entity` that has a `BooleanProperty` called `checked`. Furthermore, let there be a table column as follows:

```
TableColumn<Entity,Boolean> checkBoxColumn;
```

Then the setter for the cell value factory has the following signature:

```
setCellValueFactory(Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Entity,Boolean>,ObservableValue<Boolean>> value)
```

The following code should suffice to enable a column with checkboxes bound to the `checked` properties of the corresponding Entity-objects:

```
setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Entity, Boolean>("checked"));
checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkBoxColumn));
```

My question in its simplest form: How does a `CheckBoxTableCell` set the value of the backing property considering the fact that the cell value factory returns an `ObservableValue<Boolean>` and not, e.g., a `BooleanProperty`?

The only way how I can imagine how this is done is that the `CheckBoxTableCell` dynamically checks whether the reference returned by the cell value factory is actually a reference to a property and then binds this property to the checked property of the checkBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way how I can imagine how this is done is that the
>   CheckBoxTableCell dynamically checks whether the reference returned by
>   the cell value factory is actually a reference to a property and then
>   binds this property to the checked property of the checkBox.

That's exactly what it does. Nothing sophisticated: just uses a simple `instanceof` check. The source code is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/19197d39ad7f/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.java) if you're interested enough (look at the updateItem(...) method).